# JavaFX and FXML. When are the references to components loaded into the controller class?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a very simple fxml file, with a checkbox:

```
...
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="jfx01.T01">
...
<CheckBox fx:id="checkBox1" text="CheckBox" />
...
```

the very simple controller class is the following:

```
public class T01 extends Application {

    @FXML protected CheckBox checkBox1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
         Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("t01.fxml"));   
         primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
         primaryStage.show();

         //here, here is the problem!
         System.out.println("checkBox1==null? "+ (checkBox1==null?"yes":"no"));

    }
}
```

#### The output of this basic app is:

```
checkBox1==null? yes
```

Inside the "start" method the components are obviously created, but not yet assigned to @FXML fields of the controller class. As a test that there aren't other errors, i've added a button and an event. 
There the checkBox1 IS assigned!

```
    @FXML protected void handleButton1Action(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("button pressed");
        checkBox1.setSelected(!checkBox1.isSelected());
    }
```

#### Question

If I can't use start method because init is not yet complete, what is the first method available where the init is complete and so the components are available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Controller should implement `javafx.fxml.Initializable` and override `initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle res)` method. The `CheckBox checkBox1` will be initialized and be avaliable in that `initialize` method for you by the FXMLLoader. The convenience way is to separate the Controller and Main (that extends Application) classes, so app starting/entry point and the FXML file controller should be 2 different classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the main Stage with in the Controller with this:

```
Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
```