# JavaFX UI Controls Architecture (Control+Skin) with FXML

Tags: java, model-view-controller, custom-controls, javafx-8, fxml

In JavaFX8 there is a [UI Controls Architecture](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/UI+Controls+Architecture) that is used for make custom controls. Basically is based in:

- Control.
- Skin.
- CSS.

Also, there is a [basic structure of an FXML project](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm) that is used to make GUI too. Basically:

- Control.
- FXML file.
- CSS.

I would like to use FXML with the [UI Controls Architecture](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/UI+Controls+Architecture), so my question is:

Who is the controller for the FXML file? The Skin?

I have to do something like this code below?:

```
public class MySkin extends SkinBase<MyControl> {
public GaugeSkin(MyControl control) {
    super(control);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MyView.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(control);
    fxmlLoader.setController(control);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you're on the right track with the `Skin` class being the controller for the loaded FXML file because it is the `Skin` that is responsible for defining the nodes that comprise the 'look' of a particular control.

The `Control` class itself should really only define properties that hold the state of the control and should not care how the `Skin` actually creates the view hierarchy (that is, it should only care about it's state, not how it looks).

One difference I would make is to change `fxmlloader.setController(control);` to `fxmlloader.setController(this);` so that the `Skin` class becomes the controller rather than the control itself.

Another thing you could do is to move the `FXMLLoader` logic into a base class so that you don't have to duplicate it every time you want to create a `Skin`, something like this:

```
public abstract class FXMLSkin<C extends Control> extends SkinBase<C>{

    public FXMLSkin(C control) {
        super(control);
        this.load();
    }

    private void load() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getFXML());
        loader.setController(this);

        try {
            Node root = loader.load();
            this.getChildren().add(root);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLSkin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   
    }

    protected abstract URL getFXML();
}
```

I have a [JavaFX `UserControl` on my Github](https://github.com/BenjaminGale/JavaFX-UserControl) page which does something very similar to the `FXMLSkinBase` class above. It uses a convention to load an FXML file with the same name as the derived class so that the FXML file name does not need to be specified each time. I.E. if your derived skin is called `FooControlSkin`, the control will automatically load an FXML file called `FooControlSkin.fxml`.

The class is very simple and the code could very easily be refactored into a fully featured `FXMLSkinBase` class that would meet your requirements.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that you have to use setController(.), so throw away the IDE validation advantages gained by using the fx:controller attribute in the FXML root element; this can lead to surprise runtime binding errors or NullPointerExceptions, as I discovered the hard way!

Answer (score 1):

My better way:

- removing need for `<fx:root>` as root element of .fxml file.
- removing need to call `fxmlLoader.setRoot(control);`.
- removing need to call `fxmlLoader.setController(control);`.
- allowing a Skin to be a controller automatically via `fx:controller="{controller class name}"` in FXML root element.
- allowing an IDE to highlight bogus @FXML references to FXML in ControlNameSkin class.

A proper Control class.

```
public static class ControlName extends Control {
    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        ControlNameSkin.Factory factory = new ControlNameSkin.Factory(this);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass()
                 .getResource("ControlName.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(factory);
        try {
            Node root = fxmlLoader.load();
            ControlNameSkin skin = fxmlLoader.getController();
            skin.construct(root);
            return skin;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

A combined Skin and Controller class.

```
public static class ControlNameSkin extends SkinBase<ControlName> {
    public ControlNameSkin(Factory factory) {
        super(factory.control);
        // any setup NOT using FXML references
    }

    public void construct(Node root) {
        ControlName control = getSkinnable();
        // any setup using FXML references
        getChildren().add(root);
    }

    public static class Factory implements Callback<Class<?>, Object> {
        public final ControlName control;

        public Factory(ControlName control) {
            this.control = control;
        }

        @Override
        public Object call(Class<?> cls) {
            try {
                return cls.getConstructor(Factory.class).newInstance(this);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```